# How to structure cascading properties - apply to parent element only or all child elements?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, database-design, data-structures, entity-framework-4

I have a Folder entity that can be Moderated by users.  Folders can contain other folders.  So I may have a structure like this:

```
Folder 1
    Folder 2
        Folder 3
    Folder 4
```

I have to decide how to implement Moderation for this entity.  I've come up with two options:

**Option 1**

When the user is given moderation privileges to Folder 1, define a moderator relationship between Folder 1 and User 1.  No other relationships are added to the db.

To determine if the user can moderate Folder 3, I check and see if User 1 is the moderator of any parent folders.

This seems to alleviate some of the complexity of handling updates / moved entities / additions under Folder 1 after the relationship has been defined, and reverting the relationship means I only have to deal with one entity.

**Option 2**

When the user is given moderation privileges to Folder 1, define a new relationship between User 1 and Folder 1, *and* all child entities down to the grandest of grandchildren when the relationship is created, and if it's ever removed, iterate back down the graph to remove the relationship.  If I add something under Folder 2 after this relationship has been made, I just copy all Moderators into the new Entity.

But when I need to show only the top-level Folders that a user is Moderating, I need to query all folders that have a parent folder that the user does not moderate, as opposed to option 1, where I just query any items that the user is moderating.

**Thoughts**

I *think* it comes down to determining if users will be querying for all parent items more than they'll be querying child items... if so, then option 1 *seems* better.  But I'm not sure.

Is either approach better than the other?  Why?  Or is there another approach that's better than both?  I'm using Entity Framework in case it matters.

**In response to aneroid**

> In option 1, what happens when the parent folder with the
>   moderator--user relation is removed? Do the child folders move one
>   level up?

All children are removed from the database.

> How often does a user perform an action where you need to determine if
>   he/she is a mod for that folder? The extra relations created in option
>   2 might be useful only if there are several moderators and thousands
>   of child folders to compute for the performance you want this to have.

There aren't and won't be many moderators that need access to children of items that they moderate - and if there are, the call to "UserModeratesParentOfThisFolder()" is the last check in the validation workflow, so no other use cases suffer as a result (I think).

> Also worth considering, instead of replicating the moderator-folder
>   relationship down the tree in option 2, you could do Option 3:
>   maintain the 'child folder to moderated parent folder' relationship.
>   That way, you can verify the user having mod access in two queries -
>   1) to the table that holds the child_folder_mod_parent relations and
>   then 2) to check if the user is the mod for any of the returned parent
>   folders. So even if there are multiple mods, you are replicating this
>   relationship less than in option 2.

I don't quite understand this.  How is this different from option 1?

> I do find option 2 and 3 messy, imho. #2 is less messy than #3 and if
>   it's pure performance you require (would there really be that much mod
>   activity?) then your option 2 should suffice. From a 'structure'
>   perspective, option 1 is the neatest but has its perf drawbacks. You
>   should see how bad the performance hit is in option 1 and if it is so
>   much than you would need to implement option 2 to work around it. I
>   assume you would use a stored procedure-type equivalent in the
>   underlying database for option 1. Doing it through repeated
>   back-and-forth SQL to app code calls would be a much bigger perf hit.

I don't think there will be a ton of mod activity, and I've already implemented Option 1, so I think I'll give it a go and keep option two in mind should performance become an issue.  I am curious about the third option though... any further details there would be awesome.  Thank you for your help :)

Comment: edited mine in reply to yours... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **option 1**, what happens when the parent folder with the moderator--user relation is removed? Do the child folders move one level up?

How often does a user perform an action where you need to determine if he/she is a mod for that folder? The extra relations created in **option 2** might be useful only if there are several moderators and thousands of child folders to compute for the performance you want this to have.

Also worth considering, instead of replicating the moderator-folder relationship down the tree in option 2, you could do **Option 3**: maintain the 'child folder to moderated parent folder' relationship. That way, you can verify the user having mod access in two queries - 1) to the table that holds the child_folder_mod_parent relations and then 2) to check if the user is the mod for any of the returned parent folders. So even if there are multiple mods, you are replicating this relationship *less* than in option 2.

**Comments**

I do find option 2 and 3 messy, imho. #2 is less messy than #3 and if it's pure performance you require (would there really be that much mod activity?) then your option 2 should suffice. From a 'structure' perspective, option 1 is the neatest but has its perf drawbacks. You should see how bad the performance hit is in option 1 and if it is so much than you would need to implement option 2 to work around it. I assume you would use a stored procedure-type equivalent in the underlying database for option 1. Doing it through repeated back-and-forth SQL to app code calls would be a much bigger perf hit.

**Edit/Answer in response to SB2055's edit:**

> I don't quite understand this *[option 3]*. How is this different from option 1?

In option 1, you will be using a query(s)/stored procedure to recursively go up the Folder-to-Folder relations until you find a folder which a) has a moderator and b) that moderator is the current user.
In my option 3, these recursions will be lowered (as was the aim of option 2), except that you directly know the moderated-parent(s) of any folder...in one query. In the second query, you check if `USER is in [list of mod's of folders from query 1]`.
The main thing you will be changing here is, instead of having every folder with multiple moderator relations (as with option 2, which causes a lot of added records), this only tracks its own parent OR grandparent OR greatgranparent OR... folder which is moderated. So if you had 2 moderators with 4 folders structured as above:

- in option 2, you would have the relations...

  1. Folder 1 mod by User A
  2. Folder 2 mod by User A
  3. Folder 3 mod by User A
  4. Folder 4 mod by User A
  5. Folder 2 mod by User B
  6. Folder 3 mod by User B
- in option 3, you would have

  1. Folder 1 - no parent/null (null or no record if you prefer)
  2. Folder 2 mod by Folder 1
  3. Folder 3 mod by Folder 1
  4. Folder 3 mod by Folder 2
  5. Folder 4 mod by Folder 1

  (and the mod relationship for the folder would be)

  1. Folder 1 mod by User A
  2. Folder 2 mod by User B

Those two might look equal in this example but your mod relations

- in option 2 are *almost* [number of folders **x** number of mods] (coz of folders with more than one mod).
- in option 3 are [number of folders **+** number of moderated_folders **+** number of mods] *(sort of)* since you will have many more folders than mods.

This will make a diff to the db size and the other added **benefits of option 3** vs option 2:

- db not as big
- number of Folders >> number of Mods ( `>>` is 'much greater than')
- running 2 sql queries in option #3 not that bad a perf hit as opposed to just 1 query in #2; at least not recursive like #1
- folder changes don't require you to go through the entire child tree to update all mod relations in that tree. Only the 'mod by Folder' would need to be updated.
- *[WRONG, ignore, see Folder 3 above]* the mod_by_Folder could be stored in the same table as the Folder itself (`parent_folder` would exist, then add `moderated_by_folder`) - though it's more sensible to store that separately, but... *(read next)*
- *[WRONG, ignore, see Folder 3 above]* each folder has only one entry for which folder it's moderated by (so it could stored in the `folders` table)
- *[CORRECT]* each folder will have only its parent-moderated-folders records. (if you only listed one moderated parent, you would need recursion like in opt #1 but fewer steps through in the recursion.)

Edit/PS: After seeing the chaining that would happen with the Folder-mod_by-Folder relations, I'm not sure option 3 is all that great. It's a mid-way between option 1 and option 2 in terms of added records, performance and event triggers/queries needed to maintain the folder and moderation relations (imagine a tree split in one of the child folders). It's also simpler to understand #1 and #2 when looking at the db, but that's ok. And #3 has a 2 dependent tables to update relevant to mod relations, which isn't a *simpler* solution than #2.

Comment: Thank you aneroid !  This gives me a bit to think about :p

Comment: added a PS to my answer. After giving it some thought, I'm not all for #3.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for the heads up and taking the time to think about this :)